Unable to Restrict SSH Access to a Specific IP Address - using firewalld in Rokcy Linux 9
I added firewalld rules to allow SSH only from 192.168.122.27 and block all other IPs. However, I'm unable to SSH from 192.168.122.27 as well. Why is this happening?
[admin@rockyxfce ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules
rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.122.27" service name="ssh" accept
rule family="ipv4" service name="ssh" reject


Later I used UFW ( Uncomplicated Firewall.) to achieve this. but still I am curious why firewalld is not working
